# Sed regular expression issue

Tags: php, sed

This is my PHP code for replacing all of the email occurrences from a file:

```
$pattern = "/[[A-Z0-9._%+-]+[ ]?[\(]?(@|at)[\)]?[ ]?[A-Z0-9.-]+[ ]?[\(]?(\.|dot)[)]?[ ]?[A-Z]{2,4}/i";
$string = preg_replace($pattern, "cs@test.nl", $file );
```

and it is work. I have to mention that the file is huge. It is an export from a db. I need this regular expression to use it in a sed command:

```
sed -r -i 's/[[A-Z0-9._%+-]+[ ]?[\(]?(@|at)[\)]?[ ]?[A-Z0-9.-]+[ ]?[\(]?(\.|dot)[)]?[ ]?[A-Z]{2,4}/i/cs@test.nl/g'
```

Obviously this is not working. Can someone correct the sed command  in order to make this work ? thx

Comment: Why do you need it? You can run php from the command line, too.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to move the `i` modifier into the correct position after the replacement.

```
sed -r -i 's/[[A-Z0-9._%+-]+[ ]?[\(]?(@|at)[\)]?[ ]?[A-Z0-9.-]+[ ]?[\(]?(\.|dot)[)]?[ ]?[A-Z]{2,4}/cs@test.nl/ig'
```